# What are halos?

Tags: biblical-basis, art

Art (particularly Christian art, it seems) is filled with halos.  There's halos on [Jesus at the Last Supper](http://www.paradoxplace.com/Perspectives/Venice%20&%20N%20Italy/Venice/Images/Last_Suppers/7-900/Tintoretto-LastS-SGMag-BR900.jpg); [Jesus, Moses, and Elijah at the transfiguration](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_6dKQTchkJaA/TINqtsWV-bI/AAAAAAAAUHA/U8MXHPS9ZrQ/s1600/Transfiguation+with+Moses+and+Elijah.jpg); [on angels](http://wwwdelivery.superstock.com/WI/223/1788/PreviewComp/SuperStock_1788-12955.jpg); [the virgin Mary](http://viz.cwrl.utexas.edu/files/mary_halo.gif); etc.

What exactly is a halo?  Is it biblically based?  And did Jesus (or anyone else) walk around with a halo all the time like it's depicted?

Comment: "When Moses came down from Mount Sinai, with the two tablets of the testimony in his hand as he came down from the mountain, Moses did not know that the skin of his face shone because he had been talking with God." Exodus 34:29. Not a halo, but the closest Biblical reference to something similar.

Answer (score 5):

Haloes are not limited to Christian art but have been used in depictions of key figures from lots of religions and cultures, including Ancient Greece, Buddhism, Islam and others. They don't have a Biblical basis and aren't intended to suggest there was a visible halo around the  actual people depicted.

The  [Wikipedia article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_%28religious_iconography%29#In_Christian_art) is quite comprehensive and contains some interesting information on embellishments that were added to the halos at different times to depict different things (such as members the Trinity, Beatified figures, etc)